# Insert extra blank pages after title

Tags: memoir, typography, book-design

I'm composing a book, using `memoir` and LuaLaTeX.

I have a `titling` environment for the title page, and I was requested to insert a double empty page after it. To be clear I already have the first chapter after the title on a recto page, but I need an extra full empty page (recto+verso) before it.

The thing is just inserting some empty pages then, like a double `\cleardoublepage`

Please keep in mind that it is not a "chapter-based" requirement but it is only needed in that one spot.
Can you please help?

Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Two empty pages without headers and footers, and without increasing the page counter (`\null` is short for `\hbox{}`):

  ```
  \shipout\null
  \shipout\null
  ```
- With headers and footers of page style `empty` and increasing page counter:

  ```
  \clearpage % end title page
  \begingroup
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \null
    \newpage
    \null
    \newpage
  \endgroup
  ```

  Or if the code starts after the title page(s) at the start of a odd-numbered pages:

  ```
  \begingroup
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
  \endgroup
  ```